# Using different criterion (CO2 emissions, fuel consumption) on network analyst

Tags: qgis, network-analyst, routing

i just started to use the network analysis tool from QGIS.

The problem is that the only criterion available to make the "shortest" path are time and length.

I have a layer with information like CO2 emissions, fuel consumption etc, how do I route the path that has less fuel consumption, less CO2 emissions?

I just want to add as a criterion the CO2 emissions and fuel consumption fields if possible.

Comment: welcome to GIS SE. Please ask two separate questions if you need technical solution with differente softwares, because the answer will be related to the software that you use it is possible with both software). I've edited your question for QGIS.